# Problem with HTML5 XHR FileUpload and ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using HTML5's XMLHttpRequest.

Here's my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "receive.aspx", true);
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
xhr.send($("#fileobject").files[0]);
```

On the server side, I get `0` for the `Request.Files.Count`. However if I read the input stream I get the headers of the file as follows:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarylAWVSRo5qeSpsnzn Content-Disposition:
form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="a.txt" Content-Type:
application/octet-stream

Testing

------WebKitFormBoundarylAWVSRo5qeSpsnzn--
```

The file uploaded contains only the word "Testing".

Server code:

```
Stream inputStream = Request.InputStream;
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("c:\\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream); 
fileStream.Close();
```

Is there anything I'm missing in my client Javascript which is not populating the Request.Files object on the server? Or is there any way to read just the file contents without the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using XHR2's [`FormData` API](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-formdata-interface) to create a `multipart/form-data` request body. You can append every `form-data` part by `append()` method. It also accepts a `File`.

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myfile", $("#fileobject").files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "receive.aspx");
xhr.send(formData);
```

XHR2 will take care about proper headers and request body encoding and the file will in this example be available in the server side as `form-data` part with the name `myfile`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But doesn't work in IE, including IE 10 Platform Preview 2!!! Damn IE. :(

Comment: You're welcome. IE has indeed a long way to go (not surprisingly tbh).

Answer (score 1):

The `Request.Files` collection will not be filled unless the ContentType of the request is set to `multipart/form-data`. That's why it's always empty for you.

**Update**

Here's some javascript I found on [this site](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/04/how-to-upload-arbitrary-file-contents.html), that creates the necessary headers/boundaries for a file upload. Not sure if it will work for you, but it might:

```
function fileUpload(url, fileData, fileName) {
   var fileSize = fileData.length,
     boundary = "xxxxxxxxx",
     xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.open("POST", url, true);
          // simulate a file MIME POST request.
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary="+boundary);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", fileSize);

   var body = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
   body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contents"; filename="' + fileName + '"\r\n';
   body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
   body += fileData + "\r\n";
   body += "--" + boundary + "--";

   xhr.send(body);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Have tried that. If you see my code, that line is commented. It does not show up even if I change use multipart/form-data instead of application/octet-stream

Comment: You may have other issues that are at play here, but for sure if the content type is not coming through as multipart/form-data, it will never get filled. I looked at the internal method ASP.NET uses to fill the Files collection and it is specifically looking for this.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried a regular file upload control and found a small difference in the headers. The regular upload contains the following Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMaOZwv8AOdCyW0Mc. While the xhr contains just Content-Type=multipart/form-data;. The boundary is missing. Can this be the cause? I can't add the boundary myself. It seems to be a randomly generated string

Comment: See my update. From that example, it doesn't look like it matters what the boundary text is.

Comment: Thanks Pat for the help. I used Baluc's solution above. It works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. Will live with it for the time being. This is an interesting read though http://blog.timc.idv.tw/wp-content/uploads/HTML5_AJAX_File_Upload.pdf